# Trying to edit a string at runtime

Tags: javascript, string, unicode, formatting

I am working on an embedded system that provides output strings. Some of these strings come out with custom symbols. What I am trying to do is read them and decode them into similar-looking Unicode characters. The issue I have is that, while I can inspect the messages I received in Chrome's Inspect tools (more specifically, the *Network* tab), the string is edited to the 65533 character (the replacement character).

The code I was trying to use is:

```
  textLines[3] = textLines[3].replace ("\xCD", "\x25a0");
```

The letters in the Inspect tab appear as Í (U+00CD), but in the webpage it appears as the replacement character. I already tried to set the script's encoding to UTF-16, but it doesn't work. The font I am using is Lucida Console, which should have this character.

**What can I do to be able to detect the "real" value and change it at runtime?**

EDIT:
There is no real encoding. The character is read directly from a LCD screen. The value I get for it is 205. That's the issue.

The format I am trying to decode to is UTF-16.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Due to the fact that the embedded system I am working on has non-standard characters, what I did is do the encoding by hand, before sending the output to the browser. Symbols are changed into the correct Unicode values, which then gets replaced (using `replace()`) in the Javascript script. It is a bit clumsy, but actually works.

Comment: You should have added this as a comment since it\s not an answer to your problem.

Comment: It's not clumsy.  The web uses utf-8 more but that's arbitrary.  In your design you need to choose an intermidate form.  So if in the embeded system gives you have a bit stream that has non-standard word size (ex:there are 6 bits follow by a field 3 of bits), I would standardize then to 8bit or 16bit.  Then to show then I would translate to an output format that fit the displaying of the information.  You could have many types of display. One could be an utf-16 web page.  Another could be RS-485 connection to a controller.

Answer (score 0):

Two things you have to know

- Info on encoding: What is the symbol you want to translate and what is it's encoding form in bytes?
- Info on decoding: What is the web page decoding format? (usually it's UTF-8) What is the symbol you want to show on the page and what is it's encoding form in bytes in the decoding format of the web page?

Let's say I have the symbol "é" (U+00E9) that I what transalated into "£" (U+00A3).
Let's say the source information is encoded in ISO-8859-1 (extend ASCII), so "é" is 233 (or "\xE9").
Let's say I want to show that symbol as "£" in a web page decoded as utf-8, so "£" is the two bytes 194 (or "\xC2") and 162 (or "\xA3").

Now all I have to do is find all instances of 233 and replace then as 194 and 162.

Comment: The decoding for the webpage is UTF-16. The encoding for the symbol, on the other hand, is trickier. I get the value straight from an embedded system, and it has no standard encoding (being a value that is drawn on the LCD rather than a specific character). The value I get from the system is 205.

Comment: @MKII Check [link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-16) for UTF-16.  For the info comming from the embedded system, you should do what makes sens to you.  The translation computation is the same principal.